# Understanding RESTful. URIs for complex actions

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

I'm trying to build a RESTful service, and I've faced with some problems. I'll describe these problems (questions) with an example of an imaginary RESTful service.

For example, I need a "News" service on my site. News can be of different types: local news and global news. News are added by administrator. User can view both local and global news (separately or all-together). News are shown by pages. User can view the exact news.

So, I've built such a verb-noun table for this task:

```
GET  /news               - Get all news
POST /news               - Create news
GET  /news/{id}          - Show the news with id={id}
PUT  /news/{id}          - Edit the news with id={id}
GET  /news/{type}/{page}/{per_page} - Get news page #{page} of type {type}
GET  /news/{page}        - Get news page #{page} of both types
```

So, there are problems:

1) how to distinguish {page} and {id}? maybe {id} can be only number, but {page} - a string, started with 'p' (for example 'p1'}?

2) User can change the value "per_page" - how many news are shown on a page. Isn't it too complicated - `/news/{type}/{page}/{per_page}`? How it can be simplified?

3) How should be URLs in browser look like on this services? URLs won't be exact as URIs from table above?
For example:

```
/news - Viewing news (1st page with default 'per_page' and default 'type')
/news/{type} - Viewing news (1st page with default 'per_page' and type={type})
/news/{id} - Viewing exact news with id={id}
/news/{type}/{page}/{per_page} - Viewing exact page of news of exact type.
```

4) Additional functional. For example filter search ( getting news by date, author or title).
How to realize this with REST? How filter object (xml or json) should be transmitted? How to make URL of page with results of the filter? `/news/{date:12.12.2012,author:'admin'}` or something better?

Sorry for my rough English, If you see some grammar and etc mistakes - feel free to correct them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not too proficient with REST, but how about introducing a pseudo-type of news called 'all' to display all news - so the last URL (/news/{page}) would be changed to /news/all/{page}? This way, you don't have a conflict with ids. As for the {page}/{per_page} - maybe instead of it do {start}-{end}, so instead of 2/10 (page 2, 10 per page) it would be 10-20 (show news# 10-20)? Seems more self-descriptive to me.

Comment: @Seramme, thank you. `/news/all/` really helps in such a case. `{start}-{end}` sounds good, but it means, that calculating pages is now client-side task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you should use regular params for the type, page and per_page. Type, Page and Per_Page do not represent unique Resources, but are rather filters to the collection of News Resources. So I'd do

- `/news`
- `/news/{id}`
- `/news?type={type}&amp;page={page}&amp;per_page={per_page}`

Same for additional filtering.

Make sure to check out http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2

Comment: I'm novice to REST, so I have a question: Is it normal, that I should parse both `/such/a/thing/` and `?param=value&param2=value` thing?

Comment: @Innuendo yes, `/thing` represents a resource, while `?param=foo` represents a specific state of that resource.

Comment: One note: {type} (+'all') could be included in uri part, but paginating is better done as usual request params.

Answer (score 1):

As **Gordon** wrote, you can use request params as normal. Remember that REST doesn't means only clean and nice urls.

So, leave ids and type parameters in uri, but pagination params add with query string.

**Also**, to distinguish different uri parts, you could use pattern used in Google's [gdata](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/gdata/) i.e. params are preceded with name

```
/news
/news/id/{id}
/news/type/{type}
```

with some parsing on server side, you could add many parameters, optional parameters and not enforce exact ordering.